# External database path as parameter for parametrized query to Access

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I'm writing small VB.Net app which should build reports based on data gathered from some external MDB-files (Access 2007). It was planned that this app will use parametrized SQL queries to collect data. One of the parameters for these queries is path to the external MDB-file.

Here goes sample code:

```
Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" _
                                & "Data Source=C:\Temp\Temp.mdb;")
conn.Open()

Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand()
cmd.Connection = conn
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * INTO Trend FROM TI IN '?' WHERE TI.Id=?;"
With cmd.Parameters
    .Add("@p1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "C:\Temp\Source.mdb"
    .Add("@p2", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 5
End With

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
conn.Close()
```

Looks simple but it doesn't works. After launch my app throws following exception - **System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Disk or network error**.

Have spent a whole day to make it work with no success. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Check if the file "C:\Temp\Temp.mdb" exists, if it exists then go thru this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q251254/

Comment: Check out this link as well. http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/26/Parameter-Queries-in-ASP.NET-with-MS-Access

Comment: Yeah, have read this article. No luck. It's seems that it somehow connected with first parameter, because when I exlude 1st param and replace **CommandText** value with **"SELECT * INTO TREND FROM TI IN 'C:\Temp\Source.mdb' WHERE TI.IdentKp =?;"** it works like a charm /

Comment: Jet doesn't accept a parameter for the IN file target; it has to be a literal value.

Comment: @HansUp So this is a database engine limitation, not the data provider, right? That's too bad for me, cause I really doesn't like the idea to connect to each mdb-file to get data from it. Is there any other alternatives exist?

Comment: Yes, if you go into Access directly you will see the same thing.  Not that it matters in this case, but the engine also will not accept a parameter for the FROM.

Comment: With Jet as your database engine, I don't see how you can do it without building it into CommandText at runtime. Seems you're aware of the risk there.  You would have to validate it adequately before building the SQL.

Comment: Nothing in an  Access/Jet/ACE FROM clause is parameterizable (unless it's inside a subquery, of course).

Comment: @HansUp, @David-W-Fenton Ok, got it. Thanks for helping me. Question closed.

Comment: @me9a6yte: could be good to leave the question open in case someone else with the same problem comes looking...

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: add your comment as an answer and I for one shall upvote it...

Comment: @me9a6yte: ...hopefully you can 'Accept' an answer at some point :)

Comment: @onedaywhen: yep I hope so too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a comment that others have suggested is the answer to the question:

Nothing in an Access/Jet/ACE FROM clause is parameterizable (unless it's inside a subquery, of course).

With Access/Jet/ACE your only choice is to use some other method to write the FROM clause on-the-fly.